# Shuffle in caffe with multiple tmdbs

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am using caffe and the lmdb database to feed my data to the network. However, I have two different lmdbs for input and ground_truth since my ground_truth are images as well. Is it possible to use shuffle anyways? If yes, can I just set `shuffle: true` for both lmdbs as param?

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_value: X
  }
  data_param {
    source: "..."
    batch_size: X
    backend: LMDB
  }
```

Comment: does lmdb support `shuffle` parameter?

Comment: Yes it does, but I am using two different lmdbs. @Inman

Comment: I couldn't find shuffle in caffe.proto in lmdb param. Could you point it out please? I thought it is in hdf5.

Comment: Line 795: [link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto)

Comment: I think I got confused as you said imagedata layer with lmdb. How do you feed imagedata layer with lmdb? Are you using your own python layer? Can you show your prototxt?

Comment: Done. See above @Inman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you use layer type `"Data"` you can't use `shuffle` as there is no shuffle parameter in `data_param`.
2. As for layer type `"ImageData"` you can't use `lmdb` as data source as `source` file should be a text file with `image address and label`. But it has `shuffle` parameter. If you look inside [image_data_layer.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp) you'll find if `shuffle` is `true` then image sources are shuffled in each `epoch` using `Fisher–Yates` [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). If you use two different `ImageData` layer then `ShuffleImages()` will be called for each of them and it is unlikely that two shuffle will generate the same sequence. So you can't use `shuffle` in any of these two `ImageData` layer.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought. Thx